# jQuery continuous grow/shrink

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, infinite-loop

I'd like to draw attention to certain images on my site by making them grow and shrink slightly, over and over.

I'm not sure how to go about making this kind of infinite animation. Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure this code runs **after** the image has loaded. My demo does this by running after `window.load`, not after `document.ready` (which fires too early in Chrome).

#### HTML

```
<img id="kitteh" alt="awwww" src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
```

#### JavaScript

```
var $img = $('#kitteh'),
    scale = 1.1,
    h = $img.height(),
    sh = h*scale;

function scaleUp($elt)
{
    $elt.animate({height: sh}, function ()
    {
        scaleDown($elt);
    });
}

function scaleDown($elt)
{
    $elt.animate({height: h}, function ()
    {
        scaleUp($elt);
    });
}

scaleUp($img);
```

***[Demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/8WSRM/)***

Comment: Thanks for this. I chose it as the correct answer because it accounts for running after the image has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
var intDuration = 1000; //time in ms
setInterval(
   function(){
      $('selector').animate(/*some animation*/,'slow');
   }, 
   intDuration
);
```

`setInterval` will make the function repeat every `intDuration` milliseconds :-)

check it out in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/cf4jt/

That example uses:

JS:

```
var intDuration = 2000; //time in ms
setInterval(
   function(){
       $('#image').animate({"width": "-=100px"},'slow').delay(1000)
           .animate({"width": "+=100px"},'slow');
   }, 
   intDuration
);
```

HTML:

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/350/0000FF" id='image'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, something like:

```
function grow(factor) {
  if (factor === undefined) factor = 2;
  $('img').each(function() {
    $(this).animate({'width': $(this).width() * factor, 'height': $(this).height() * factor}, 2000);
  });
}

function shrink(factor) {
  grow(1.0/factor);
}
```

Or your can use LightBox for jQuery :) http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way by creating a plugin to pulse any set of elements you specify:

```
$.fn.pulseSize = function() {
    var pulseTime = 2000,
        pulseDiff = 10;

    this.animate({height:'+='+pulseDiff,
                  width:'+='+pulseDiff},pulseTime*.2,function(){
        $(this).animate({height:'-='+pulseDiff, 
                         width:'-='+pulseDiff},pulseTime*.8,function(){
            $(this).pulseSize();
        });
    });
};

$('div.pulse').pulseSize();
```

[**See example →**](http://jsfiddle.net/z7URq/2/)